# Use another variable when it's not specified in Python's argparse module

Tags: python, argparse

Is it feasible to use a variable which is also another argument variable when the first argument is not specified in argparse?

So in the following code:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_option('-f', '--file', dest='outputfile')
parser.add_option('-d', '--db', dest='outpufDB')
```

And when I run the above script via `script.py -f file_name`, and don't specify the argument on `outputDB`, then I want to set the same value on `outputDB` as on `outputfile`. I know using `default` argument enables to set default value, but is it also feasible to set default value derived from another argument?

Thanks.

Comment: The traditional way to do this is to give it some useless "sentinel"  default value, and then, after parsing arguments, if `outputDB`'s value is that sentinel, use `outputfile`'s value instead. (But I'm only adding this as a comment, because I know `argparse` does all kinds of cool things that I haven't fully dug into yet, so there may be a nifty direct solution.)

Comment: That looks a good idea. I assumed there are some styles of passing the argument to another more elegantly, but I can readily accept the way you suggest. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traditional way to do this (the way people did it going back to old Unix getopt in C) is to give `outputDB` a useless "sentinel" default value. Then, after you do the parse, if `outputDB` matches the sentinel, use `outputfile`'s value instead.

---

See [`default`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#default) in the docs for full details on all of the options available. But the simplest—as long as it doesn't break any of your other params—seems to be to leave it off, and pass `argument_default=SUPPRESS`. If you do that, `args.outputDB` just won't exist if nothing was passed, so you can just check for that with `hasattr` or `in` or `try`.

---

Alternatively, you can pass an empty string as the default, but then of course a user can always trigger the same thing with `--outputDB=''`, which you may not want to allow.

To get around that, you can not give it a `type`, which means you can give any default value that isn't a string, and there's no way the user can pass you the same thing. The pythonic way to get a sentinel when `None` or the falsey value of the appropriate type isn't usable is:

```
sentinel = object()
x = do_stuff(default_value=sentinel)
# ... 
if x is sentinel:
    # x got the default value
```

But here I don't think that's necessary. The default `None` should be perfectly fine (there's no way a user can specify that, since they can only specify strings).

---

(It's quite possible that `argparse` has an even cooler way to do this that I haven't discovered, so you might want to wait a while for other answers.)

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean in `sentinel = object()` and `x = do_stuff(default_value=sentinel)`... isn't it enough to just write `if options.outputDB == 'sentinel': options.outputDB = options.outputfile`? (assume I add `default='sentinel'` to `outputDB`'s add_option?

Answer (score 0):

The simple approach - do your own checking after parse_args.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-f', '--file', dest='outputfile')
parser.add_argument('-d', '--db', dest='outpufDB')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.outpufDB is None: 
    args.outpufDB = args.outputfile
```

The default default value is `None`, which is easy test for.

Doing something entirely within `argparse` is useful if it is reflected in the `help` or you want the standardize error message.  But you are just filling in a default after parsing.

I can imagine doing the same with a custom '-f' Action, but the logic would be more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a good practice, but I tried this on a similar problem. I have adapted the following snippet for your code, hope it helps.

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_option('-f', '--file', dest='outputfile', default='dummy_file')
parser.add_option('-d', '--db', dest='outputDB', default=parser.parse_args().outputfile)
```

If you don't pass any arguments the name of both, the 'outputfile' and 'outputDB' will be 'dummy_file'.